# making my own game engine : function to determine the terrain the player is walking on

Tags: c

I am currently working on my making my own 2d game engine in C, and I want to be able to determine what terrain (grass, dirt, road) the player is walking on, to then be able to play a different walking sound according to the terrain.

So far I have come with a simple way of determine the terrain :

- pick multiple pixel around the player position.
- calculate the average screen color at the player position.
- compare the average color with an array of color, use a formula to determine how close the color are, keep the closest color and return the corresponding terrain.

It's kinda work but not very effective and often does not return the terrain name I want, So my question is :
 Are there any alternative way of doing this ? or is there anything wrong with my code that alternate the result ?

Here is the part of my code that determine the terrain :

```
static void internal__analyser_set_reference(color_ref_t **reference)
{
    reference[0]->name = fill("grass");
    reference[0]->color = (sfColor){0, 86, 111, 27};
    reference[1]->name = fill("water");
    reference[1]->color = (sfColor){0, 38, 68, 92};
    reference[2]->name = fill("dirt");
    reference[2]->color = (sfColor){0, 83, 60, 44};
    reference[3]->name = fill("road");
    reference[3]->color = (sfColor){0, 70, 70, 70};
    reference[4]->name = fill("black");
    reference[4]->color = (sfColor){0, 0, 0, 0};
    reference[5]->name = fill("blood");
    reference[5]->color = (sfColor){0, 116, 30, 12};
    reference[6] = NULL;
}

static char *internal__terrain_analyser(sfColor average)
{
    color_ref_t **reference = malloc(sizeof(color_ref_t) * 6);
    int difference = 1000;
    int smallest = 1000;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        reference[i] = malloc(sizeof(color_ref_t));
    internal__analyser_set_reference(reference);
    for (int i = 0; reference[i] != NULL; i++) {
        difference = sqrt(pow(reference[i]->color.r - average.r, 2)+pow
        (reference[i]->color.g - average.g, 2)+pow
        (reference[i]->color.b - average.b, 2));
        if (difference < smallest) {
            smallest = difference;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return reference[index]->name;
}
```

struct :

```
typedef struct color_ref_t
{
    sfColor color;
    char *name;
} color_ref_t;
```

thanks you in advance !

Comment: You might want to repost this question to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com.  But while I'm commenting: I think it's kind of weird you're trying to figure out what kind of ground the character is walking on by looking at the (colour of) the ground under the character's feet.  Doesn't the game have a map which tells what the ground is like at each patch ?  And from which the game-rendering part of the engine determines what colour to draw on screen ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't storing the terrain type directly instead of using colors? That would simplify the calculation quite a bit

Comment: Also you have a bug in this line: `color_ref_t **reference = malloc(sizeof(color_ref_t) * 6);` - you aren't allocating the correct size ( `sizeof(color_ref_t)` vs `sizeof(color_ref_t*)`)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I could. But what if I want to make a game with my engine where the terrain can change during the game ? for exemple I could add blood on the background texture when I kill an enemies which then change the terrain.

Comment: @unholySheep didn't notice that mistake, thanks you !

Comment: Well if blood transforms the ground from firm to soft going, you'd update the map.  Or you'd have a map with multiple layers, or something.  But hey, it's your game, I'm just a random stranger on the internet offering 'helpful' advice.  Feel free to ignore it.

Comment: I am not ignoring it, and I do consider using your idea don't worry I was just looking at a way to read terrain that would update if I make change to the texture. thanks you !